# Laravel EC2 Odd Issue

Tags: laravel

I'm currently working on a Laravel + Vue application with inertia. Running my local environment with sail, everything works perfectly on my local machine,
but deploying it on ec2 instance I'm facing problems that I find strange.
I already made sure that I have the same version of php, node , npm , vite on sail.

Example Scenario:

On one of the SPA pages when adding a record, it won't reflect on the page
but would show after you add another record or refresh the page. (it's like fetching the previous state )
the same for update and delete.

I put a console.log on my axios call on getting the data   "console.log(response.data)"
and it is really not returning the updated data.

Its hard to replicate on my local machine since it is working fine, but just having this problem only in EC2. Appreciate the help

Comment: can you check the logs folder ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator checked the logs, seems no errors with regards to the issue though